# Kafka Streams, Process API and Schedule using Key

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have Kafka Topic consist of 256 partitions, where data with below format stored, and the ID is used as key.

```
{
    "id":<UUID>,
    "userId":<Users-UUID>,
    // rest of the key-value are omitted for brevity
}
```

Due to resource availability and other systems limits, for a given user, we can process up to N events per sec.

I am using the **Kafka Streams Process API** with State Store and **would like to create a schedule task for each of the user.**

Based on resource availability, will process the event for a given user. If no resources are available, nothing will be processed.

Since the ID is used as key, and the app is horizontally scaled, **how will I be able to groupBy the stream using the user id so that all events belongs to a user lands on to a particular app instance** and get stored in only one app's state store.

I dont want to schedule a user task in multiple app instance because dont want to get into coordinations related implementation later.

Comment: Send  user id as  key and message as  value. So that all events/messages having same user ID will go into the same partition then your consumer application assigned to that particular will process all messages of that particular user. Even when you scale application horizontally, partition will be assigned only to only consumer app.

Comment: Unfortunately using the user id as key is not an option, because 1) User id does not give us the correct and required key distribution and parallelism  2) Changing this is not possible because it affects other apps in production.

Comment: 1) Then write your own producer

Comment: No such option because the producers are running outside of the system which i dont have control to.

Comment: You say in your question: `the ID is used as key` -- so data should already be partitioned by key? If not, how is data distributed?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax - ID is used as the key to get better parallelism. Using the `user id` does not give us desired parallelism and also user id will make one partition overloaded with huge data. However, to support new  requirement, I need to aggregated using `user id`. So when i consume, id is the key but the aggregation/group by should be applied using `user id`.

Comment: If you need to aggregate by `user id`, you need to ensure that data with the same `user id` goes to the same partition. If `user id` itself does not give you good balancing, you need to use some custom partitioning strategy.